# Is Solidity creating an implicit getter for a nested contract that is created?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, state-variable

Is Solidity creating an implicit getter or not for a nested contract that is created?

Example:

```
contract Foo {
   ....
}

contract Bar {
    Foo public foo;

   Bar() {
        foo = new Foo();
   }
}
```

When trying this out using Truffle, it tells me that `Bar.foo()` is not part of the ABI.

Am I doing something wrong, or is `foo()` just not being created by the Solidity compiler?
(I'd expect it to return the address of the created `Foo()` contract)

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 contracts definition in one sol file, ContractA and ContractB, And you want to deploy ContracB, then use it like this:

```
var ContractB = artifacts.require("ContractB")

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ContractB, '750000000000000000000000000', 'MyCoinName', 18,{gas: 4700000})
};
```

Note: .sol shouldn't be used and name of the contract to be deployed is used.

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity 0.5.x you have explicitly cast a contract as an address. There is more than one way to write the function to return the contract address. To observe "implicitly" in the question ...

```
contract Foo {
   ....
}

contract Bar {
   Foo foo;
   address public fooAddress;

   Bar() {
        foo = new Foo();
        fooAddress = address(foo);
   }
}
```

So, `thisContract.fooAddress()` returns the `address` of `foo`.

Hope it helps.